# How to change display the equation into f(x)=0.0667*x in MATLAB command window?

Tags: matlab, printf

I have a MATLAB code

```
clear all;
clc;
syms x;
f=2/30*x;
f=vpa(f,3);
fprintf('f(x)=%s\n',char(f));
```

The result is

```
f(x)=.667e-1*x
```

Now I want to display in command window:

```
f(x)=0.0667*x
```

Anyone can help me how to display the equation into `f(x)=0.0667*x` in command window? I don't know how to do it.

ADDENDUM

My command window show
[image]

I have tried on command window:

```
>> get(0,'format')

ans =

short

>> syms x
>> f=2/30*x;
>> f=vpa(f,4);
>> fprintf('f(x)=%s\n',char(f));
f(x)=.6667e-1*x
```

Comment: your code displays for me the result you want `f(x)=0.0667*x`

Comment: I use MATLAB R2014b and the result is `f(x)=.667e-1*x`

Comment: @OngkyDennyWijaya what's your output when you run this in the command window: `get(0,'format')`

Comment: `>> get(0,'format')

ans =

short`

Comment: so update to matlab 2020 ?